# Ошибка ESLint Initialization error (ESLint). Unexpected token }Initialization error (ESLint). Unexpected token } catch {

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint, prettier

Использую nuxt:2.14.12, версия node.js - 14, npm - 7.7
Подключил  ESLint. Редактор кода WEbstorm. Вот настройки линтера в редакторе [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я запускаю линтер, то он выдает следующую ошибку.

`Initialization error (ESLint). Unexpected token { /home/user/projects/vue/monitoring-frontend/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js:421 } catch {`

Вот конфигурация моего .eslintrc.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот package.json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже, как будто парсер не распознаёт [optional catch binding](https://2ality.com/2017/08/optional-catch-binding.html), что странно, так как Node.js поддерживает это с 10-й версии. У вас там точно нигде не затесалась старая Node.js? Может, используется старый Eslint c устаревшим нестандартным парсером (у вас в настройках вроде выбран парсер от babel)?

Comment: У меня несколько версий node.js. Я их переключаю через nvm. Но последние 3 месяца постоянно сижу на 14

Comment: А версия Eslint или парсера от Babel не устарели? Может, если обновиться до последних, наладится?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, Версия  ESLInt 7, я добавил в тексте вопроса скрин моего  package.json

Comment: Насколько я могу судить, https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint теперь deprecated, то есть он устарел и не обновляется. На замену ему пришёл https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser , там есть объяснения, как перейти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня была такая же проблема. Дело было в том, что в настойках IDE стояла неверная версия ноды (из-за NVM) [image]

После выбора правильной версии проблема исчезла